# jQuery form validation (almost got it... I think)

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

```
Trying to Do form validation using Jquery.  When I click submit, my page         reloads and the form entry is never checked.  I have been hacking at this for     hours. Any help appreciated.
Here is my Html Page:
it won't let me post the code, says I need to space with 4 spaces??
```

So my link is here...
[Link to my flight entry validation page](http://sotd.us/jared_freese/NodeJS/flightentry.html)

Comment: Please read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Include this line at the last in your HTML.

```
 <script src="http://sotd.us/jared_freese/NodeJS/flightscript.js"></script>
```

i.e.

```
    <script   src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script   src="http://sotd.us/jared_freese/NodeJS/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-form-validator/2.3.26/jquery.form-validator.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://sotd.us/jared_freese/NodeJS/flightscript.js"></script>
```

You should always load 3rd party libraries first before using them in your script.

The browser loads all scripts sequentially as they encounter them.

Comment: Thank you! I'll give it a shot

Comment: still no go, it just loads the page back up, and never checks validation...